# Division In SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I am wanting to divide a int quantity by a number, but my output is not what I am after.  This is my DDL

```
Create Table Orders 
(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
    ,partid varchar(100) NOT NULL
    ,qtyordered int DEFAULT '0'
    ,orderedby varchar(100) NOT NULL
    ,ordereddate date DEFAULT GETDATE()
)

Insert Into Orders (partid, qtyordered, orderedby) VALUES
('SS100', 10, 'James'), ('RR200', 5, 'Bob'), ('NN300', 3, 'Jake'), ('OO400', 5, 'Blue')
```

Now I have trired using the SQL Server functions `Ceiling()` and `Floor()` but I am not getting my desired output.  This is the query I tried, what do I need to do in SQL Server to get an output of 2, 2, 1?

```
Select
partid
,CEILING(qtyordered/3) As [First] --want to be 2
,CEILING(qtyordered/3) As [Second] --want to be 2
,FLOOR(qtyordered/3) As [Third] --want to be 1
FROM Orders
WHERE partid = 'RR200'
```

Comment: And for `partid = 'SS100'`? What should it return? 4,4,3 or 4,3,3? In other words, should the 3 values add exactly to `qtyordered`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due 'qtyordered' is an integer, you need to either, CAST/CONVERT it to decimal, or use a decimal/float value. (3.0)

> ```
> Select
> partid, qtyordered
> ,CEILING(qtyordered/3.0) As [First] --want to be 2
> ,CEILING(qtyordered/3.0) As [Second] --want to be 2
> ,FLOOR(qtyordered/3) As [Third] --want to be 1
> FROM Orders
> WHERE partid = 'RR200'
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> partid | qtyordered | First | Second | Third
> :----- | ---------: | :---- | :----- | ----:
> RR200  |          5 | 2     | 2      |     1
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e714c97772aa8921999001e5f1676cd3)*

According to MS DOCS, [CEILING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ceiling-transact-sql) returns same type as the numeric expresion:

> **Return Types**
>   Returns the same type as numeric_expression

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh - Why? Because if all the terms in the equation are integers, SQL will return an integer result. And CEILING(1) = 1. Make sure at least one value has a digit right of the decimal point, and SQL won't pre-force the result to integer for you.

Comment: @RDFozz you're right, edited.

Answer (score 4):

I assume that do **not** have to or want to use `CEILING` and `FLOOR` but the aim is to divide the `qtyordered` value into 3 integer values - that are as close to each other as possible - and that when you then add them you'll get back the original value.

While for value `5` the ceiling-ceiling-floor methods works ok, if `qtyordered` is `10` (or `4` or `7` or `13` or ...), you'll get `4,4,3` which add back to `11` and not `10`!

You can achieve consistent (mathematically) results using only integer arithmetic. The trick is to start from the "third" value, i.e. the value that will be the smallest of the three:

```
   "Third"  =  qtyordered / 3
```

then subtract that value from `qtyordered` and divide by 2:

```
   "Second" = (qtyordered - "Third") / 2
```

and then subtract both "Third" and "Second" from `qtyordered` to find the "First":

```
   "First"  = qtyordered - "Second" - "Third"
```

The query becomes:

```
SELECT 
   partid,
   qtyordered,
   qtyordered - (qtyordered - qtyordered / 3) / 2   
                            - qtyordered / 3        AS [First], 
                (qtyordered - qtyordered / 3) / 2   AS [Second],
                              qtyordered / 3        AS [Third] 
FROM 
    Orders ;
```

Test at [dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=4eb9aa07e9edf59244e5a25f5f4bc800).

The code and the logic behind it is more clear if we use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT 
   partid,
   qtyordered,
   [First], 
   [Second],
   [Third] 
FROM 
    Orders 
  CROSS APPLY
    ( SELECT [Third]  = (qtyordered)                      / 3 )  AS q3
  CROSS APPLY
    ( SELECT [Second] = (qtyordered - [Third])            / 2 )  AS q2
  CROSS APPLY
    ( SELECT [First]  = (qtyordered - [Third] - [Second]) / 1 )  AS q1
 ;
```

The expression `"First"  = qtyordered - "Second" - "Third"` assures that the 3 values will add up to the original `qtyordered`. Combined with the other 2 expressions, it's easy to show that:

```
"Third" <= "Second" <= "First"
```

and that the difference `"First" - "Third"` is either 1 or 0, so the three values are as close as possible to 1/3 or `qtyordered`.