# Function To Perform Calculations Based Off Variable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I saw an answer by @ypercubeᵀᴹ that gave a great answer on how to calculate what appeared to be a quantity ordered by 3 and give whole number answers. Which that got me thinking, how would you handle a situation if there was a variable number of times to split?

Meaning this was the OP where you would always split by 3 ([Original Poster](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/168833/division-in-sql)

```
Create Table #Orders 
(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
    ,partid varchar(100) NOT NULL
    ,qtyordered int DEFAULT '0'
    ,orderedby varchar(100) NOT NULL
    ,ordereddate date DEFAULT GETDATE()
) ;

Insert Into #Orders (partid, qtyordered, orderedby) VALUES
('SS100', 10, 'James'), ('RR200', 5, 'Bob'), ('NN300', 3, 'Jake'), ('OO400', 5, 'Blue') ;

SELECT 
   partid,
   qtyordered,
   [First], 
   [Second],
   [Third] 
FROM 
    #Orders 
  CROSS APPLY
    ( SELECT [Third]  = (qtyordered)                      / 3 )  AS q3
  CROSS APPLY
    ( SELECT [Second] = (qtyordered - [Third])            / 2 )  AS q2
  CROSS APPLY
    ( SELECT [First]  = (qtyordered - [Third] - [Second]) / 1 )  AS q1;
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=bd4d0a168558a0782242d3c31223b6ea)*

However, what if instead of always splitting by 3, you had an int variable that stated how many times to split, say same DDL but instead of splitting by 3 you use

```
Declare @TTS int = 5
```

And now you split each scenario 5 ways instead of 3.  Basically a re-usable function that can "on-the-fly" split based off a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I've used a recursive function to calculate each int item, and a dynamic query to pivot the result.

> ```
> Declare @TTS int = 5
>
> --= Add divisors 
> ;with AddDiv as
> (
>     SELECT partid, qtyordered, t.divisions
>     FROM   #Orders
>     CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP (@TTS) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY S.[object_id]) [divisions]
>                  FROM    sys.all_objects S) t
> )
>     --= Recursively calc every int item
>     , CalDiv as
>     (
>         SELECT partid, qtyordered, divisions, 
>                part = qtyordered / divisions, rest = qtyordered - (qtyordered/divisions)
>         FROM   AddDiv WHERE divisions = @tts
>         UNION ALL
>         SELECT ad.partid, ad.qtyordered, ad.divisions,
>                part = rest / ad.divisions, rest = rest - (rest / ad.divisions) 
>         FROM   AddDiv ad 
>         INNER JOIN CalDiv cd 
>         ON ad.partid = cd.partid
>         WHERE ad.divisions = cd.divisions - 1
>     )
>     SELECT * 
>     INTO   Results
>     FROM   CalDiv;
> ```

And now the dynamic PIVOT:

> ```
> DECLARE @col AS nvarchar(MAX),
>         @cmd AS nvarchar(MAX);
>
> SET @col = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(divisions) 
>             FROM Results
>             FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
>             ).value('.', 'nvarchar(MAX)') 
>            ,1,1,'')
>
> SET @cmd =   'SELECT partid, qtyordered, ' + @col
>            + ' FROM'  
>            + ' (SELECT partid, qtyordered, divisions, part'
>            + ' FROM Results) src'
>            + ' PIVOT (MAX(part) FOR divisions IN (' + @col + ')) pvt';
>     
> EXECUTE (@cmd);
> ```

And this is the final result:

> ```
> partid | qtyordered | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5 
> :----- | ---------: | :- | :- | :- | :- | :-
> NN300  |          3 | 1  | 1  | 1  | 0  | 0 
> OO400  |          5 | 1  | 1  | 1  | 1  | 1 
> SS100  |         10 | 2  | 2  | 2  | 2  | 2 
> RR200  |         15 | 3  | 3  | 3  | 3  | 3
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=0fe73173071aa5793c1a6f6fad9bf679)*

This is my first answer, It uses a function to build a comma delimited string with all int items.

> ```
> Create Table #Orders 
> (
>     id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL
>     ,partid varchar(100) NOT NULL
>     ,qtyordered int DEFAULT '0'
>     ,dividedBy int DEFAULT 1
>     ,orderedby varchar(100) NOT NULL
>     ,ordereddate date DEFAULT GETDATE()
> ) ;
>
> Insert Into #Orders (partid, qtyordered, dividedBy, orderedby) VALUES
> ('SS100', 10, 3, 'James'), ('RR200', 15, 6, 'Bob'), ('NN300', 3, 2, 'Jake'), ('OO400', 5, 4, 'Blue') ;
> GO
> ```

> ```
> CREATE FUNCTION fnCF(@Qty decimal, @TTS int)
> RETURNS varchar(1024)
> AS
> BEGIN
>     DECLARE @step int = 0;
>     DECLARE @sv varchar(1024) = '';
>     DECLARE @Q0 int;
>     DECLARE @Q1 decimal;
>     
>     SET @step = @TTS
>     SET @Q1 = @Qty
>
>     WHILE  @step > 0
>     BEGIN
>         SET @Q0 = @Q1 / @step;
>         SELECT @sv = @sv + CAST(@Q0 AS varchar(100)) 
>         SET @step = @step -1
>         SET @Q1 = @Q1 - @Q0
>         IF @step > 0 
>         SET @sv = @sv + ', '
>     END
>     
>     return @sv;
> END
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>    partid,
>    qtyordered,
>    dividedBy,
>    dbo.fnCF(qtyordered, dividedBy) divInt
> FROM 
>     #Orders;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> partid | qtyordered | dividedBy | divInt          
> :----- | ---------: | --------: | :---------------
> SS100  |         10 |         3 | 3, 3, 4         
> RR200  |         15 |         6 | 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3
> NN300  |          3 |         2 | 1, 2            
> OO400  |          5 |         4 | 1, 1, 1, 2
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=41daa5c0a717ef4384e1ae97da896d5d)*

Answer (score 5):

Basically, we're just looking to spread the remainder from the division out over the values. This procedure does exactly that; it will return a table with the result vals from the split. I assume we do not want to return a variable number of columns (depending on the divisors we receive), and I decided that actually generating the text "First", "Second", etc. wasn't really a part of the question, so I'm returning each value in its own row.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE split_into_ints(@dividend int, @divisor int)
AS
BEGIN
    WITH result_rows AS
         (SELECT TOP (@divisor) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o1.object_id)
                 as result_num
            FROM sys.objects o1 CROSS JOIN sys.objects o2
         )
        ,base_vals AS
         (SELECT @dividend / @divisor as base_result
                ,@dividend % @divisor as remainder
         )
    SELECT r.result_num
          ,CASE WHEN r.result_num <= remainder THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + v.base_result as result_val
      FROM base_vals v CROSS JOIN result_rows r
     ORDER BY result_num
END;
GO
```

The following:

```
EXECUTE split_into_ints 10,3;
EXECUTE split_into_ints 49,6;
EXECUTE split_into_ints 2000,11;
```

Yields these results:

```
result_num           result_val
-------------------- -----------
1                    4
2                    3
3                    3

result_num           result_val
-------------------- -----------
1                    9
2                    8
3                    8
4                    8
5                    8
6                    8

result_num           result_val
-------------------- -----------
1                    182
2                    182
3                    182
4                    182
5                    182
6                    182
7                    182
8                    182
9                    182
10                   181
11                   181
```

Alternately, you could make this an inline table-valued function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_split_into_ints(@dividend int, @divisor int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN
(
    WITH result_rows AS
         (SELECT TOP (@divisor) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY o1.object_id)
                 as result_num
            FROM sys.objects o1 CROSS JOIN sys.objects o2
         )
        ,base_vals AS
         (SELECT @dividend / @divisor as base_result
                ,@dividend % @divisor as remainder
         )
    SELECT r.result_num
          ,CASE WHEN r.result_num <= remainder THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
           + v.base_result as result_val
      FROM base_vals v CROSS JOIN result_rows r
);
GO
```

You run the same queries as above thusly:

```
SELECT * FROM fn_split_into_ints(10,3);
SELECT * FROM fn_split_into_ints(49,6);
SELECT * FROM fn_split_into_ints(2000,11);
```

Results are the same. To answer one comment: this would allow you to pull `result_val` into a variable:

```
SELECT @result_val = result_val
  FROM fn_split_into_ints(49,6)
 WHERE result_num = 6
;
```

EDIT: Changed function name, so function and procedure can co-exist (if you'd want them to, for some reason).